# How to combine several linear regression function into one

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, linear-regression

I have the relationship between *f* and each of other five variables, the relationships are acquired by linear regression and are as follow

$f = a{\tiny1}x{\tiny1} + b{\tiny1}$

$f = a{\tiny2}x{\tiny2} + b{\tiny2}$

...

$f = a{\tiny5}x{\tiny5} + b{\tiny5}$

I am thinking since the regression is already done and all *x* variables are related to the same *y*, and the range of *y* and *x* are the same (ranging from 0 to 100). I can just add those five linear functions together and do a normalization or scaling. Then, by feeding the added-up function like

$f = $$\sum_{i=1}^5 (Ai*Xi + Bi)$

with $x{\tiny1}, x{\tiny2}, .., x{\tiny5}$, I can get only single one *y* value.

Can anyone tell is this way valid, if so, in my case *a*'s range is [0, 1], however, for the intercept *b*, they are quite large, how can I do the normalization or scaling in order to obtain a valid and reliable value *y*?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of your data. I.e., if you can view it as $n$ vectors of a kind
$$
(y_i, x_{1i}, x_{2i}, ..., x_{ni}), \quad i=1,...,n
$$
then a multiple linear model should fit to the task, namely
$$
y=\beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^5\beta_jx_j + \epsilon.
$$
That you can estimate using any statistical software.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't have the variable vector, however I have the linear relationship between y[i] and each x[ni]. Is that possible to derive a function as you wrote above? I think it might be possible since the range of y and x are the same, but I'm not sure.

Comment: By "range" you mean that $x$ and $y$ get values on the same scale? Anyway, I don't understand how your data set looks like. Can you post a sample of some rows or write down example with similar structure?